# After removing ubuntu, I still have traces of it in my boot order

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

for a while now, I've been trying to dual boot kali linux and windows 8 and failing. I think a reason for that might be is because I still have traces of ubuntu (I had it installed before, formatted its parition, booted a live CD and used boot repair so that it boots automatically into windows and grub is removed)

Even after doing that, I still see traces of ubuntu in my boot order

It literally says
`Internal CD DVD/ROM drive`
`Ubuntu`
`Ubuntu`
`Hard disk`

There are two entries of ubuntu even though I don't have it anywhere, if I boot into them I get presetened with `grub>` command line

How do I remove these two entries?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `efibootmgr` tool. 
Run

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

to get a list of numbers for boot entries. Then

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 4 -B
```

to delete entry number 4. 
Never run this tool on Apple notebooks - it bricks them.

Comment: "...on Apple notebooks - it bricks them." praised be all who don't give a damn about standards, best practices and interoperability.

Comment: I guess on Apple you'll have to install some sort of EFI shell and manipulate from it.